# List<double> for value of dictionary lookup specific item

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, key-value

I have a Dictionary with 5 different doubles in the list.  I know the order of each item in the List.  I am trying to find a one liner piece of code where I can lookup a specific value in my list given the key.

So something like:

```
double myDbl = myDict["key"][value[3]];
```

Is something like this possible, I cant find it anywhere.  Thanks

Comment: Have you declared the dictionary as Dictionary<string, List<double>> ?

Comment: You're question's very unclear at the moment. We have little idea how your dictionary is declared, or what the results of your experimentation have been.

Comment: Problem solved, needed just a [3] instead of looking for the value property of the dictionary

Comment: Why are people so concerned with writing oneliners that don't really benefit the readability or performance of the code? Write a method that checks that the key exists in the dictionary, and will fetch the value for you. Then guess what: that method is your one-liner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, if this is a `Dictionary<string, List<double>>` you *could* just use

```
double value = myDict["key"][3];
```

However, this line:

> I know the order of each item in the List.

makes me think that *actually* you should restructure your code. If you know that the first item always represents one piece of data (e.g. weight), the next always represents another (e.g. height) etc, then you should just create a new type with those properties. Using a `List<double>` for this will make the code much harder to maintain... it doesn't naturally *reveal* the information about what each value means.

Once you've changed it to, say, a `Dictionary<string, Person>` you can use:

```
double height = myDict["key"].Height;
```

which is significantly clearer.

Of course it's possible that you meant something else by the line I've quoted...

Comment: +1 for cutting through the murk of the question to the heart of the beast. (Maybe.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dictionary defined as

```
Dictionary<string,List<double>>
```

And assuming the dictionary elements are initialized correctly you can do the following:

```
myDbl = myDict["key"][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be something like:

```
double myDbl = myDict["key"][3];
```

As you're looking for index 3 from the resulting list from the `key`

By understanding the order in which the operators are executed, you can see that `myDict["key"]` will return your value type, which here is assumed to be `List<double>`. From this return value, you then want to get the 4th object (0 based) so you use `[3]` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
Dictionary<string, List<double>> l_dict = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
l_dict.Add( "key", new List<double>( new double[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } );
```

Then:

```
List<double> l_valueCollection = l_dict["key"];
double l_value = l_valueCollection[3];
```

Or, more succinctly (the "one-liner" you wanted):

```
double l_value = l_dict["key"][3];
```

Comment: Thanks, I was close!  I kept trying to look for a property "Value" and then look up the index.  That was easy.  Thanks

Comment: @Ron - Also see Jon Skeet's answer. You may find it more helpful. Don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your collection looks like this:

```
Dictionary<string,List<double>> myDictionary;
```

Then the following will work:

```
double myDouble = myDictionary["key"][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method like this that returns your value, no matter what key you pass in.

```
    private double GetValue(Dictionary<string, double> dict, string key)
    {
        return (from pair in dict where pair.Key == key select pair.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Remember that this is using LINQ and will only work with .Net Framework 3.5

Comment: Why would you want to turn an O(1) operation into an O(n) operation? Using TryGetValue will allow for the same result much more efficiently. Oh, and LINQ doesn't need .NET 4.0 - it was introduced in 3.5.

Comment: @JonSkeet Because doing it like this is better practice and the code is at the same place. And yes LINQ was in 3.5 my mistake.

Comment: This is absolutely *not* better practice. I wish I could downvote multiple times. You've got a dictionary, which is optimized for lookup by key: if all you want to do is fetch the value associated with a key, you should *not* iterate over all entries. Note that also, you haven't even addressed the question - which was admittedly somewhat unclear - where the value isn't a `double` but a `List<double>`.